# Stub response for Request NPM module in unit test in order to test pipe()

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, stub, npm-request

In my Express (NodeJS) application I am using the request library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). The endpoint I am requesting triggers a data download which I pipe into a local file.

```
function downloadData(filePath) {
    request
      .get(http://endpoint)
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath))
      .on('response', function(response) {
         console.log(response);
       })
      .on('finish', () => { console.log("finished!"); })
```

My unit test uses Mocha and Chai. I inject my file location to write to and then read from the file to see if the expected data is there.

```
it('should write data to a file', (done) => {
    const requestStub = sinon.stub();
    proxyquire('../../download-data', {
      'request' : requestStub,
    });
    requestStub.returns("Download Succeeded");

    DownloadData.downloadData("./test.json")

    fs.readFile('./test.json', (err, data) => {      
       expect(data.toString()).to.eq("Download Succeeded");
       done();
    });
  });
});
```

When run, the test output is ' ' (empty String) instead of the expected String. This means that either my `pipe()` is not writing data correctly or my request stub is not returning (or acting) how I want it to. None of my `console.log` functions print (i.e. I do not see a 'response' or 'finished!'). Any thoughts on how to stub a request in order to write a small amount of data to a file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a timing issue.

Add a callback to your `downloadData` function and do the `fs.readFile()` test after `downloadData` finishes, e.g.

```
function downloadData(filePath, cb) {
  request
    .get(http://endpoint)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath))
    .on('response', function(response) {
       console.log(response);
     })
    .on('error', cb)
    .on('finish', () => { cb(null) })
 }
```

Then in your test do:

```
it('should write data to a file', (done) => {
    const requestStub = sinon.stub()
    proxyquire('../../download-data', {
      'request' : requestStub,
    })
    requestStub.returns("Download Succeeded")

    DownloadData.downloadData("./test.json", function (err) {
      fs.readFile('./test.json', (err, data) => {      
        expect(data.toString()).to.eq("Download Succeeded")
        done()
      })
    })
  })
})
```